# $u_j =∑^k_{i=1}a^i_jv_i$ show $f(u_1,...,u_k) = (\text{det} A)f(v_1,..., v_k)$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, differential-forms

Let $f$ be a $k$-covector on a vector space $V$. Suppose two sets of vectors $u_1,...,u_k$ and $v_1,..., v_k$
in $V$ are related by
$u_j =∑^k_{i=1}a^i_jv_i, j = 1,..., k,$
for a $k ×k$ matrix $A = [a^i_j]$. Show that
$f(u_1,...,u_k) = (\text{det} A)f(v_1,..., v_k)$

---

I can write $f(u_1,...,u_k)=f(\sum^k_{i=1}a^i_1v_i,..., \sum^k_{i=1}a^i_kv_i)=
a^1_1a^1_2a_3^1...a^1_kf(v_1,v_1,...,v_1)+a^2_1a^2_2a_3^2...a^2_kf(v_2,v_2,...,v_2)+...+
a^k_1a^k_2a_3^k...a^k_kf(v_k,v_k,...,v_k)=$

$$=\sum^k_{i=1}\bigg(\prod ^k_{j=1} a^i_j \bigg)f(v_i,...,v_i)$$

A hint on how to continue ?

Comment: Are you sure about your computations? Shouldn't there be mixed terms like $f(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k)$ for instance?

Comment: @Didier $a^1_1$ will go in the first $v_1$ $a^1_2$ will go in the second $v_1$ etc, i think this is correct, if i add the first $2$ I get $f(a^1_1v_1+a^2_1v_2,...)$

Comment: Well, if $k=2$, $f(a_1^1v_1+a^2_1v_2,a_2^1v_1+a_2^2v_2) \neq a_1^1a_2^1f(v_1,v_1) + a_1^2a_2^2f(v_2,v_2)$. You missed some terms, e.g, $a_2^1a_1^2f(v_1,v_2)$. You should try $k=2$,  then $k=3$ before trying to generalise to arbitrary $k$. The fact that $f$ is alternate, so that $f(v_1,v_1)=f(v_2,v_2)=0$ will also be useful.

Comment: @Didier I did, but I must have missed something. ok i will fix this, then again how do I proceed , somehow it should appear the sgn function.

Comment: Hint: if $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$, then $f(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)}) = \mathrm{sign}(\sigma) f(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$. Use the fact that the group of permutations is generated by transpositions + the fact that $f$ is alternate.

Comment: @Didier are you saying that $\sum^k_{i=1}\bigg(\prod ^k_{j=1} a^i_j \bigg)f(v_i,...,v_k)=\sum_{σ\in S_k}\bigg(\prod ^k_{j=1} a^i_{σ(j)} \bigg)f(v_{σ(i)},...,v_{σ(i)})$? , I don't think I quite get it, should I just have faith ?

Comment: No, I don't say that. What I say is that $f(a_1^1v_1+a_1^2v_2,a_2^1v_1+a_2^2v_2) = a_1^1a_2^1f(v_1,v_1) + a_1^1a_2^2f(v_1,v_2) + a_1^2a_2^1f(v_2,v_1) + a_2^1a_2^2f(v_2,v_2)$. Since $f$ is alternate, $f(v_1,v_1)=f(v_2,v_2)=0$ and $f(v_2,v_1) = -f(v_1,v_2)$, hence the all thing is equal to $(a_1^1a_2^2 - a_1^2a_2^1)f(v_1,v_2)$. You should now recognize the determinant. Now, try to generalize that by yourself.

Comment: @Didier thanks for the help, I think I can handle this.

Comment: Does $k$-covector mean alternating $k$-tensor to you? You need alternating for this result to be at all correct. I do not like the terminology, I confess.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes it's alternating

Comment: @TedShifrin I confess neither do I.